# How to manage millions of tiny HTML files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, file

I have taken over a project which is a Ruby on Rails app that basically crawls the internet (in cronjobs). It crawls selected sites to build historical statistics about their subject over time.

Currently, all the raw HTML it finds is kept for future use. The HTML is saved into a Postgres database table and is currently at about 1,2 million records taking up 16 gigabytes and growing.

The application currently reads the HTML once to extract the (currently) relevant data and then flags the row as processed. However, in the future, it may be relevant to reprocess ALL files in one job to produce new information.

Since the tasks in my pipeline includes setting up backups, I don't really feel like doing daily backups of this growing amount of data, knowing that 99,9% of the backup is just static records with a practically immutable column with raw HTML.

I want this HTML out of the PostgreSQL database and into some storage. The storage must be easily manageable (inserts, reads, backups) and relatively fast. I (currently) have no requirement to search/query the content, only to resolve it by a key.

The ideal solution should allow me to insert and get data very fast, easy to backup, perhaps incrementally, perhaps support batch reads and writes for performance.

Currently, I am testing a solution where I push all these HTML files (about 15-20 KB each) to Rackspace Cloudfiles, but it takes forever and the access time is somewhat slow and relatively inconsistent (between 100 ms and several seconds). I estimate that accessing all files sequentially from rackspace could take weeks. That's not an ideal foundation for devising new statistics.

I don't believe Rackspace's CDN is the optimal solution and would like to get some ideas on how to tackle this problem in a graceful way.

*I know this question has no code and is more a question about architecture and database/storage solutions, so it may be treading on the edges of SO's scope. If there's a more fitting community for the question, I'll gladly move it.*

Comment: Will you access them randomly and very often? What you may keep locally (in a specific DB table) is a small **cache** of frequently accessed (and/or newer) files. 1000/2000 files may be a good cache and consume just few MB. BTW that table should also be excluded from backup (rebuilt on demand).

Comment: Currently, the application reads them only once to extract the currently relevant data and then flags the row as processed. However, in the future, it may be relevant to reprocess ALL files in one go to produce new information. I estimate that accessing them sequentially from rackspace will take weeks. That's not ideal.

Comment: I don't understand: if network access is so slow then why don't you move them to a local storage? They'll be backed-up according to _normal_ incremental backup rules (modification date) and they'll be quickly accessible when required (even faster than store them in DB). HTML files are also pretty easy to compress (in average 300~400%) then a big DB table where you store not individual files but big file groups of tar.gz binary blobs can also help.

Comment: I want the application to be deployable across multiple servers, so I am reluctant to use the first application server as file server.

Comment: Unfortunately PostgreeSQL has not any support for something liks MSSQL FILESTREAM (AFAIK!!!).

Comment: Have you thought about http://redis.io/ as a storage?